# Issue with DLL files

Tags: c++, windows, dll, allegro

http://pastebin.com/ZLbRhnTi

Here's the code, I can't get my PC to find the files.

'SPGAME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\matth_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SPGAME\Debug\SPGAME.exe'. Symbols loaded.

'SPGAME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'SPGAME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'SPGAME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'SPGAME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'SPGAME.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\alld42.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Just ignore it. None of these are fatal errors, it simply means you cannot use the debugger to step into those DLLs with full source display.

Comment: A [Program DataBase (PDB) file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) contains debugging information for the debugger. What the "errors" are saying is that the debugger can't find those debug files for the system libraries, something which you don't actually need since you're never going to need to debug those libraries (unless you get work as a system library developer at Microsoft, in which case you will have access to the debugger files). Running or debugging your program will work fine anyway without those files.